# Checking list's elements function

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, syntax

Suppose I have a list of the form `x={{a,b},{n1,n2,...}` where n1,n2... are integers.
I want to write a function that checks whether each of n1,n2, etc. is greater than a limit. If that's the case `x` is set to `0.`, else the function returns `x`.

```
fc[x_List] :=Module[{i, l}, l = Length[x[[2]]];
For[i = 1, i <= l, i++, If[x[[2, i]] > smax, x = 0.; Break[]]];
x];
```

Let's try it:

```
smax = 2; x = {{1,5}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}; 
fc[x]
(*=> fc[0.] *)
```

and not `0`. What am I doing wrong in the definition of `fc` ? Also, is there a way to write `fc` without usinf the `For` loop?

**EDIT**
After discovering `AnyTrue` thanks to the answer of @SneezeFor16Min who mentions `AllTrue` the answer is

```
Clear[fc]
fc[x_List] := If[AnyTrue[x[[2]], # > smax &], 0., x]
```

Comment: (1) `Scan` can replace `For` in this case. (2) `x` in the definition of `fc` is a `List`, not a `Symbol`, so `x = 0.` is equivalent to `{{1,5}, {1, 2, 3, 4}} = 0.` which won't work. You should use temporary variable for return.

Comment: Or you can use `GreaterThan[smax]` (not a big deal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend my comment, I'd like to notice that we seldom need to write `For` loops ourselves in Mathematica; if any, it's slow and can be rewritten with stuff like `Do` or `Scan`. Here you just want to check if all elements satisfy some condition (*i.e.*, do not exceed `smax`), which is already built in, `VectorQ` or `AllTrue`:

```
fc[x : {_, n_}] := If[VectorQ[n, # <= smax &], x, 0.]
```